# Removing a specific string in the array using a List Array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am creating a simple Bingo game.

I stored the different number in a String Array

```
    String[] number = new[] { "" };
    
    if (lblLetter.Text == "B")
    {
        //number = new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15" };
    }
    if (lblLetter.Text == "I")
    {
        //number = new[] { "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30" };
    }
    if (lblLetter.Text == "N")
    {
        //number = new[] { "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45" };
    }
    if (lblLetter.Text == "G")
    {
        //number = new[] { "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60" };
    }
    if (lblLetter.Text == "O")
    {
        number = new[] { "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75" };
    }
```

I used a List Array to store the numbers that was already selected on the bingo thus should be removed on the String Array

```
public List<string> exceptions = new List<string>();
```

Appending the label Value to it

```
exceptions.Add(lblNumber.Text);
```

Now I want to remove specific Items on String Array that is found on the exceptions List String

I'm confused on how to do this, Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please explain more in detail

Comment: The exceptions list string contains the numbers I want to remove on number list array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Except`.

```
number = number.Except(exceptions).ToArray();
```